# how to show a link only on my own profile node?

Tags: privatemsg

tried this code:

```
<?php
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1)){
$url = privatemsg_get_link(array(user_load($node->uid)));
print '<div class="pm">'. l(t('Send a private message to the author'), $url, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'lichnoe'))) .'</div>'; 
}
?>
```

but this doesn't works. It displays on my own profile, but doesn't displays on other user's profile. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused about a couple of things. 

You're using $user and $node interchangeable when they are indeed not the same thing. 

Also you're comparing arg(0) to 'user' and arg(1) to the uid which makes me think you're on a user/uid page yet you're using the $node object.

What's the path of the page? Is it a node page or a user account page?

Are you using the global user object? Is so you should show it on the code, it makes it seem incomplete.

Comment: I'm using this on a user profile page (With content profile). Adress is users/heihachi. I'm just printing $profile['content_profile']; node in a user-profile.tpl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted above will check if you are on the `user/[uid]` page for the user that is logged in. So it will take effect for the user's own user page. If you wanted to post the link on all pages except the user's own page you should instead do

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && $user->uid != arg(1)) {
```

Comment: Can you please explain that arg() system in drupal, how it does work? Or where i can read about it?

Comment: @Heihachi It get url args, check the api: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7